# css/html my background does show up but its behind my divs

Tags: html, css, background

My problem is that my background is there, but it's behind my `div`s. I want it to be on the sides of the content div but it won't work. This is the part I think the problem is:

```
body {
    background-image:"C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\achtergrond.png";
    background-color:;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:1500;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

And this is the whole css code:

```
body {
    background-image: "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\achtergrond.png";
    background-color:;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 1500;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

.class1 A:link {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #bababa;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.class1 A:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #bababa;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.class1 A:active {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #bababa;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.class1 A:hover {
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
}

.class2 A:link {
}

.class2 A:visited {
}

.class2 A:active {
}

.class2 A:hover {
}

.class3 A:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000080;
    text-align: center;
}

.class3 A:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000080;
    text-align: center;
}

.class3 A:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000080;
    text-align: center;
}

.class3 A:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000080;
    text-align: center;
}

.class4 {
    background-image: "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\achtergrond.png";
}

#content {
    margin-top: 20;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    height: 1000;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    margin-bottom: 10;
    padding: 20;
    background: "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\achtergrond.png";
}

#footer {
    background-color: #FFA500;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}

#header {
    background-color: #FFA500;
}

#menu {
    background-color: #bababa;
    height:;
    width: 100%;
    float: center;
}

#container {
    background-image: "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\achtergrond.png";
}
```

and this is my html

```
<html>
<head>
<LINK HREF="C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\Hetstylesheet.css"      REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css">
</head>
<body background="C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\achtergrond.png">
<div id="container" style="width:*">


<div id="header">
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Onze server webpagina</h1>IP:</div>

<div id="menu">
<span class="class1">
<li><a href="C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\Homepage.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\Server.html">De Server</a>  </li>
<li><a href="C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\Updates.html">Updates</a></li>
<li><a href="C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\Loes haar gedeelte.html">loes</a></li>
</span>

<span class="class3">
<div id="content">
<br><P Style="font-size:18pt;"><strong>WELKOM</p></strong></style>
<br><br>Hoi, diegene die dit ziet.<br>
VEEL PLEZIER!!!
</div>


<div id="footer">
Copyright © Peter Kingma</div>
</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Forward thanks

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle

Comment: You can use `Homepage.html` instead of `C:\Users\Peter\Documents\onze server met div\Homepage.html` - as if you upload this to a web-server, none of the paths will work.

Comment: Also your HTML is invalid in places. You don't have a `<ul>` around your list items. And `body background="` isn't valid.

Comment: with your answer/help i found the answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one approach (not using inline CSS would be preferred) or another, as you've got two different Background declarations going on. One inline, and one in your stylesheet.

In your stylesheet you've got a couple of things that are fighting/canceling each other as well:

```
body {
    ...
    min-height: 100%; /*max-height:100%; will prevent an image from scaling larger than it's true size */
    height:1500; /* this is the height you'll get no matter what, by setting it explicitly
}
```

`<body background="this will override your stylesheet">` ... I'd remove it.

To your question ... `<body>` will ALWAYS be behind your content divs, and those divs will always be children of `<body>`. If you want to use a background image that appears to be on the side of a `<div>`, all you need to do is make sure `<body>` stays wider than the BG Image + width of the `<div>`s + any side margins you want/need.

```
body {
   background:url(your.png) right 0; /* aligned to the right */
   background-size:80px 60px; /* CSS3 not good for older browsers (using an image you know is 80px wide, for example, would work best for browser compatibility. */
   min-width:###px; /*body bg img + width of div + any margins you want. */
}

div {
    max-width:###px; /* follow <body>s rule from above */
}
```